# F# interactive notebooks in vscode: Getting the notebook location

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, f#

The fine folks of [dotnet interactive](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive) have just released notebooks for dotnet 5.0. I'd like to use the notebooks to load in a csv file and play around with parsing data.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to correctly specify the csv file path, which lives in the same folder as my notebook, `~/Developer/myRepo.fs`:

```
printfn $"{System.Environment.CurrentDirectory}"
// /Users/muel42/Library/Application Support/Code - Insiders/User/globalStorage/ms-dotnettools.dotnet-interactive-vscode

printfn $"{__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__}"
// /Users/muel42/Library/Application Support/Code - Insiders/User/globalStorage/ms-dotnettools.dotnet-interactive-vscode
```

Do I have to specify an absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After restarting VS Code and loading the notebook, both `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` and `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` give me the directory of the current notebook.